# Filter single item from a List

Tags: list, filter, elixir, enumerable

Given:

```
iex(9)> list_of_maps = [%{"a" => 1, "b"  => 2, "c" => 3},%{"a" => 66, "b"  => 1, "c" => 9},%{"a" => 66, "b"  => 20, "c" => 8}]
```

I can do:

```
iex(10)> Enum.filter(list_of_maps, &(&1["a"] == 1))                                                                                                                                                                
Enum.filter(list_of_maps, &(&1["a"] == 1))                                                                                                                                                                         
[%{"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3}]
```

However now comes the part I dread writing in every language - getting the first value of this list to extract the single item.

Is there some standard function in elixir that filters a list, returning  single item if there is only one item after a filter is applied, or a list of items if there are numerous items returned after the filter is applied? Like:

```
iex(11)> Enum.filterr(list_of_maps, &(&1["a"] == 1))                                                                                                                                                                
Enum.filter(list_of_maps, &(&1["a"] == 1))                                                                                                                                                                         
%{"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3}

iex(12)> Enum.filterr(list_of_maps, &(&1["a"] == 66))                                                                                                                                                                
Enum.filter(list_of_maps, &(&1["a"] == 66))                                                                                                                                                                         
[%{"a" => 66, "b"  => 1, "c" => 9},%{"a" => 66, "b"  => 20, "c" => 8}]]
```

Comment: FYI if you just wanted the first one, there's `Enum.find/2`.

Comment: I'm curious why you need this though. Wouldn't this require adding a special case to handle lists of maps and just maps to whatever function you plan to call after getting the result from your `filterr/2`?

Comment: @Dogbert Not sure if I understand the question correctly,  (reading ' lists of maps and just maps' as ' lists of **maps** and _just_ **maps**' - but  in the case that a single item is selected, there seems to be no special case required - that's what is expected. However I can see now that if a single item is expected, using `Enum.find/2` displays clearer expectation of a single item returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Find one item from a List

If you want to filter a list to *get only one item*, use [`Enum.find/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#find/3):

```
Enum.find(list_of_maps, fn m -> m["a"] == 1 end)
```

---

## Get one or a list of matches

To handle both cases, pattern matching is the way to go:

```
defmodule MyEnum do
  def filter(list, fun) do
    list
    |> Enum.filter(fun)
    |> normalize
  end

  defp normalize([item]), do: item
  defp normalize(list),   do: list
end
```

You can then use it like this:

```
MyEnum.filter(list_of_maps, &(&1["a"] == 1))
```

It will return a list if there are multiple matches or the map itself if there's only one match.

Answer (score 1):

Just pipe your filtered list into `Enum.at/2`

```
first = list_of_maps |> Enum.filter(&(&1["a"] == 66)) |> Enum.at(0)
```

That will get the first element of the filtered list regardless of size.

Also, as Dogbert mentioned in the comments you can just use `Enum.find/2` instead of filter to just find the first match.

```
Enum.find(list_of_maps, &(&1["a"] == 66))
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some standard function in elixir that filters a list, returning single item if there is only one item … or a list of items if there are numerous items

No, but pattern matching makes it trivial:

```
def single_or_many([single]), do: single
def single_or_many(many), do: many
```

And if you wanted to treat the empty list specially (before the 'many' case):

```
def single_or_many([]), do: :nil
```

Then, the function call chain would be:

```
list_of_maps
|> Enum.filter(&(&1["a"] == 1))
|> single_or_many
```